# Alien Voice design questions 

Tags: voice-manipulation, sound-design

I was wondering if some folks can help put me in a quick direction to achieve this effect.

I need to make a "telepathic voice" speak as if it were a crowd, choir. I have been given a choir recording that I am supposed to use and the director will perform the voice of the alien to the flow of the choir and would like the alien to have the timbre of the choir but intelligibility of the dialogue. While still maintaining a cool and creepy effect.

Layering, chorus / delay come to mind and I will play with this. We just don't have that much time and would love to have some assistance with direction, would vocoding this work?

I dont own a vocoder for and am working in Pro Tools. But would also like to consider that route if anyone has had success with a specific plug in or workflow.

Looking forward to giving this a try over the coming week, will be fun for sure.

thanks

Comment: Try using the recording of the choir in a convolution reverb with the dialog, it makes for some cool effects.

Comment: Tks Stephen I had not thought of that. Will give it a shot with Tl space. Do you recommend a length for the clip used? I wonder for different phrases if using various "impulses" via snapshot would be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

What you have already planned to do sound good. A vocoder is a wonderful choice, but since you don't have one i have another idea for you.

Download FL Studio 10 demo. It should be fully functional mostly except the fact that you cannot save the project. It has a bunch of tools that you can use to get this FX right long as you know how to tweak it right, i know you said that you don't have much time.

If you download try using these:

Fruity Vocoder

Vocodex

Newtone

after you have done that you should be able to render it as a wav or mp3 as needed for the project.

I did something simular to this using the tools i told you (mostly just a nice synth sound and vocoder) to make a robotic voice for a commentator. My Girl Friend was the voice over talent, check it out.

First FX at about 40 seconds

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObPMsyyZfV8&list=UUp7O2yMl5nflYxTex_kLf4Q&index=4&feature=plcp

If you have any other questions feel free to ask!

first FX at about 2minutes:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7prqyMBMi7g&list=UUp7O2yMl5nflYxTex_kLf4Q&index=3&feature=plcp

Comment: Thanks great idea however, If we need to revisit the effect once the trial expires we would be stuck since it can't save and were not investing in fruity loops. I will probably stick with effects in pro tools to ensure future proofing otherwise great work around!! Tks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://soundcloud.com/george-v/v-dusk-falling-sfx The fourth sound effect was designed exactly for a telepathy scene in a video game. Lots of layering, delay, convolution reverb, highpass filters, nothing special. Just experiment with different fx on layers, and some delays on the master.